# What's the proper way to calculate ROI per year given the ROI for a period of time?

Tags: investing, loans, peer-to-peer-lending, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to figure out what would be my yearly ROI if I know my ROI for a given period of time.

On May 1st, I started invested 8.82 BTC in loans on BitLendingClub and now (August 6th) I have 9.33 BTC. For the 97 days I've invested, my return has been 5.78%. Does that mean that my yearly return will be `(5.78% / 97 days )*360 days = 21.45%`?

Comment: Any answer will assume that this rate of return continues throughout the year.  Many things like this are cyclical and dependent on the time of year, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that return was realized, the math is 1.0578^(365/97)= 1.235 or 23.5%

If you earned 1%/month, the return is 1.01^12= 1.1268 or 12.68% per year. Interest is a power function to compound, not simple multiplication.

Comment: Glad to help. It would be great if the member downvoting would either cite my error, or offer a better answer.